# Delete all the points that are far from a segment

Tags: java, algorithm, coordinates, points

I wrote an algorithm inspired by some answers on StackOverflow : it detects points that are quite far from an infinite line. This algorithm is shown below.

However, I don't work with infinite lines in my project, but with segments. And the problem, according to me, is that if a point has the same ordinate than a segment's extremity, it will not be considered as "far from the segment".

How could I modify this algorithm to make it working with a segment, and not an infinite line please ?

```
List<Cupple> returned = new ArrayList<>(points_to_test);

for(Cupple c : points_to_test) {

    /*if(c == segment_first_point || c == segment_last_point) {
        continue;
    }*/

    if(Math.abs(Math.abs(
            (segment_last_point.getNumber(0) - segment_first_point.getNumber(0))
                    *
                    (segment_first_point.getNumber(1) - c.getNumber(1))
                    -
                    (segment_first_point.getNumber(0) - c.getNumber(0))
                            *
                            (segment_last_point.getNumber(1) - segment_first_point.getNumber(1))
    )
            /
            Math.sqrt(
                    Math.pow((segment_last_point.getNumber(0) - segment_first_point.getNumber(0)), 2)
                            +
                            Math.pow((segment_last_point.getNumber(1) - segment_first_point.getNumber(1)), 2)
            )

    ) > maximal_allowed_distance) {

        returned.remove(c);
    }
}

return returned;
```

To be sure you understand :

1. `returned` is the list with points that are on the segment, or near the segment (and the "imprecision" / maximal distance that determine if a point is out of the segment is the variable : `maximal_allowed_distance`)
2. `points_to_test` are ALL the points that are present in my graph : the both of my segment + the points that are really on the segment + the points that are almost on the segment (<= `maximal_allowed_distance`) + the points that are far from the segment (> `maximal_allowed_distance`). **The idea of my little algorithm is that I remove all the latter.**
3. `segment_[first|last]_point` are the two segment's extremities
4. `c` is the current point of `points_to_test` and I want to know if it is far from the segment or in (according to the `maximal_allowed_distance`)
5. **`getNumber(0)` returns the X coordinate of the point, `getNumber(1)` returns the Y one.**

---

## Important edit : implementation of the muzzlor's solution

```
public static List<Point> getOnlyOnSegmentPoints(Point segment_first_point, Point segment_last_point, List<Point> points_to_test, double maximal_allowed_distance) {
    System.out.println("=== Segment : " + segment_first_point + " - " + segment_last_point);
    double segment_first_point_x = segment_first_point.getNumber(0);
    double segment_first_point_y = segment_first_point.getNumber(1);
    double segment_last_point_x = segment_last_point.getNumber(0);
    double segment_last_point_y = segment_last_point.getNumber(1);
    double test_x, test_y;
    double k_numerator, k_denominator;

    Point p;
    List<String> coords_p = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Point> returned = new ArrayList<>(points_to_test);

    for(Point point_to_test : points_to_test) {

        if(point_to_test == segment_first_point || point_to_test == segment_last_point) {
            continue;
        }

        test_x = point_to_test.getNumber(0);
        test_y = point_to_test.getNumber(1);

        // k = ((x - a).(b - a))/((b - a).(b - a))
        k_numerator = (test_x - segment_first_point_x) * (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x)
                + (test_y - segment_first_point_y) * (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y);

        k_denominator = (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x) * (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x)
                + (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y) * (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y);

        // p = ((x - a).(b - a))/((b - a).(b - a)) (b - a) + a
        coords_p.add(
                ""
                        + (

                        ((test_x - segment_first_point_x) * (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x)) // "((x - a).(b - a))"
                                /
                                (0.00001+ // "((b - a).(b - a))"
                                        (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x) * (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x)

                                )

                                *
                                (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x) // "* (b - a)"

                        +

                        segment_first_point_x) // " + a"
        );
        coords_p.add(
                ""
                        + (

                        ((test_y - segment_first_point_y) * (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y)) // "((x - a).(b - a))"
                                /
                                (0.00001+ // "((b - a).(b - a))"
                                        (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y) * (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y)

                                )

                                *

                                (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y) // "* (b - a)"

                        +

                        segment_first_point_y) // " + a"

        );
        p = new Point(coords_p);

        if(k_numerator/k_denominator < 0 && EuclidianFilters.distanceBetweenTwoPoints(point_to_test, segment_first_point) > maximal_allowed_distance) {
            returned.remove(point_to_test);
            System.out.println("------> Point removed x-a : " + point_to_test);

        } else if(k_numerator/k_denominator >= 0 && k_numerator/k_denominator <= 1 && EuclidianFilters.distanceBetweenTwoPoints(point_to_test, p) > maximal_allowed_distance) {
            returned.remove(point_to_test);
            System.out.println("------> Point removed x-p : " + point_to_test);

        } else if(k_numerator/k_denominator > 1 &&  EuclidianFilters.distanceBetweenTwoPoints(point_to_test, segment_last_point) > maximal_allowed_distance) {
            returned.remove(point_to_test);
            System.out.println("------> Point removed x-b : " + point_to_test);
        }

    }

    return returned;
}
```

## Screenshot illustrating the execution

As you can see, for the Segment : (1 ; 2 ; 0 ) - (1 ; 0 ; 0 ), the point (1 ; 1 ; 0) is considered as too far from it. However, it must be considered as part of this segment.

[image]

Comment: I deleted my answer as it is didn't account for all points correctly :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove points that are far from a segment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207514/how-to-remove-points-that-are-far-from-a-segment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any point on the line can be represented as by the equation:

```
v = a + k (b - a)
```

Take the projection of your point onto that line and determine the value of `k`. You can then set up some basic logic based on the values of `k` (`k < 0`, `k` in `[0, 1]` and `k > 1`) plus some geometry to calculate the distance from the line segment.

**Edit:** Going to expand more on this because I realise it was a little terse

I'm going to represent vector variables by single letters because I don't want to have to expand this out, . will represent dot product.

You have a point `x`, you want to look at its projection `p` onto that line, and then represent it by the formula above:

```
p = ((x - a).(b - a))/((b - a).(b - a)) (b - a) + a
```

From this formula, we can see that the value of `k` is going to be the coefficient here:

```
k = ((x - a).(b - a))/((b - a).(b - a))
```

Now if `k < 0`, you're going to want to take `||x - a||`, if `k` in `[0, 1]`, then you're going to want to take `||x - p||` as your distance and if  `k > 1`, you want `||x - b||`

**Edit 2:**

Just to clarify, while I used single letters for my vector variables, I also used a single letter for `k` but it should be thought of as a scalar. Note that it's just made from dot products and so only ever takes on a scalar value. As an example, if we want to break down `p` into components `(p_x, p_y)`

```
 p_x = k * (b_x - a_x) + a_x
 p_y = k * (b_y - a_y) + a_y
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but I think I did a mistake in the implementation of your algorithm (I edited my question). Indeed, you can take a look at my screenshot, I commented it a little, underlining the problems : points belonging to the segment are considered to be far from it...

Comment: You should re-use your k computation when defining p, something about one of the denominators doesn't look right: ((test_x - segment_first_point_x) * (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x)) // "((x - a).(b - a))"
                                /
                                (0.00001+ // "((b - a).(b - a))"
                                        (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x) * (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x) <--- there's nothing to do with the y values here?

Comment: To elaborate, p_x = k * (b_x - a_x) + a_x, but k should be the same as first computed

Comment: While you're debugging, also print out the value of p and make sure it sits well with you. If p isn't right, then there's an error in either calculating k or p. Also print out k, you should get 0.5 in the example you posted in your question

Comment: Yes, `p`'s coordinates seem to be bad, a `NaN` was hidden and I found it. For the point `(1 ; 0 ; 0 ; )`, I have a `k=0.0` (so that's good) but a  distance that is `NaN` , because of `p`'s coordinates. I'm looking for what is badly computed. You're focusing me on the denominators, I'm searching

Comment: I would say get rid of the re-computation of k and use (kNumerator/kDenominator) in both the p calculations

Comment: You want to say that I should replace each `p`'s coordinates' denominator entirely by `k_numerator/k_denominator` ? (and to replace each `k_numerator/k_denominator` by  a unique `k` ) ?

Comment: sure, you can do that if you want. double k_value = (k_numerator/k_denominator); p_x = k_value * (segment_last_point_x - segment_first_point_x) + (segment_first_point_x); p_y = k_value * (segment_last_point_y - segment_first_point_y) + (segment_first_point_y)

Comment: Even if I do this, the point (1 ; 1 ; 0) is considered as far from the segment [(1; 2 ; 0) ; (1 ; 0 ; 0) ] : it must not. It's the case because the distance found is : 2.0 (however, the distance should be 0 because the original point and the projected one are the same :-( )

Comment: What is the value of p after you fixed your code for this example? Should we move this conversation to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141284/discussion-between-muzzlator-and-jarsofjam-scheduler).

Comment: If I want to make use of 3D, can I keep the definition of `k` you gave above (and just modify it to take account of Z) ? And concerning `p`'s coordinates, do you know if I just have to add the Z coordinate ? `p_z = k_value * (segment_last_point_z - segment_first_point_z) + (segment_first_point_z)` ?

Comment: yes once you modify the formula for k to take into account the z component for the dot products, the same solution will work (and for higher dimensions too). The formula for p_z is correct as well

Comment: Thanks you @muzzlator !

Answer (score 2):

1) Calculate the point `p` that is on the infinite line `(a,b)` for the point `t` that you are testing.

2) Calculate how far `p` is from the point `t` you are testing, if it is too far, discard it.

3) If the x-coordinates of `(a,b)` are not equal, then check if the x-coordinate of `p` is in the range of the x-coordinates of `a` and `b`.  If so, keep the point.  If not, do a distance check from `t` to `a` and `b`, if neither is within the maximum allowed distance then discard it.

4) If the x-coordinates of `(a,b)` were equal, do the same as step 3 except comparing the y-coordinates.

Comment: I take back my comment, this solution works. Going to suggest an edit because of what confused me originally

Comment: Thanks for your solution :) - for now, I'm trying muzzlator's one