# VB6 need to have a clickable line

Tags: vb6

I am developing an application, with many lines (line controls) placed on a form. 
Also these are referred to as the "light" controls. I want want to have a click and mouse over events for these lines

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should add some more information and show some effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some maths on the mouse click event to work out if the point the mouse is at is actually on the line. You will also want to build in some tolerance a the person will likely not click exactly onto the line but a few pixels either side.

have a look at this question for a starting point: [How can I tell if a point belongs to a certain line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907390/how-can-i-tell-if-a-point-belongs-to-a-certain-line)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. But when the lines become more, it is more difficult and time consuming to calculate whether a point belongs to a line. There are clickable lines in VB.NET, however I don't want to migrate this application to it.

Comment: @user2492467 - well those are your two options. I don't think anyone can answer this question with anything else. If you agree please mark as accepted